# Speed up Multiset Permutations

Tags: python, numpy, permutation

I'm looking to speed up my code that takes ~80 milliseconds for 300 sets to generate `multiset_permutations` from `sympy`. Ideally this would take only a few milliseconds; also the more items, the slower it gets.

What can I do to make my code faster? Multi-threading? Or convert to `C`? Any help here on speeding this up would be greatly appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
from time import monotonic
from sympy.utilities.iterables import multiset_permutations

milli_time = lambda: int(round(monotonic() * 1000))

start_time = milli_time()

num_indices = 5
num_items = 300
indices = np.array([list(multiset_permutations(list(range(num_indices)))) for _ in range(num_items)])

print(indices)    

[[[0 1 2 3 4]
  [0 1 2 4 3]
  [0 1 3 2 4]
  ...
  [4 3 1 2 0]
  [4 3 2 0 1]
  [4 3 2 1 0]]

 [[0 1 2 3 4]
  [0 1 2 4 3]
  [0 1 3 2 4]
  ...
  [4 3 1 2 0]
  [4 3 2 0 1]
  [4 3 2 1 0]]

 [[0 1 2 3 4]
  [0 1 2 4 3]
  [0 1 3 2 4]
  ...
  [4 3 1 2 0]
  [4 3 2 0 1]
  [4 3 2 1 0]]

 ...

 [[0 1 2 3 4]
  [0 1 2 4 3]
  [0 1 3 2 4]
  ...
  [4 3 1 2 0]
  [4 3 2 0 1]
  [4 3 2 1 0]]

 [[0 1 2 3 4]
  [0 1 2 4 3]
  [0 1 3 2 4]
  ...
  [4 3 1 2 0]
  [4 3 2 0 1]
  [4 3 2 1 0]]

 [[0 1 2 3 4]
  [0 1 2 4 3]
  [0 1 3 2 4]
  ...
  [4 3 1 2 0]
  [4 3 2 0 1]
  [4 3 2 1 0]]]

print('Multiset Perms:', milli_time() - start_time, 'milliseconds')

Multiset Perms: 88 milliseconds
```

** Code Update to Reduce extra computations by 2/3 **

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
from time import time, monotonic
from sympy.utilities.iterables import multiset_permutations

milli_time = lambda: int(round(monotonic() * 1000))

start_time = milli_time()

num_colors = 5
color_range = list(range(num_colors))
total_media = 300

def all_perms(elements):
    if len(elements) <= 1:
        yield elements  # Only permutation possible = no permutation
    else:
        # Iteration over the first element in the result permutation:
        for (index, first_elmt) in enumerate(elements):
            other_elmts = elements[:index]+elements[index+1:]
            for permutation in all_perms(other_elmts): 
                yield [first_elmt] + permutation

multiset = list(multiset_permutations(color_range))
# multiset = list(itertools.permutations(color_range))
# multiset = list(all_perms(color_range))

_range = range(total_media)
perm_indices = np.array([multiset for _ in _range])

print('Multiset Perms:', milli_time() - start_time)

Multiset Perms: 34 milliseconds
```

Comment: I have a feeling the overhead from multithreading would actually slow this down.

Comment: Why do you recompute the same permutation `num_items` times with `for _ in range(num_items)`? Is it only for the benchmark?

Comment: @JérômeRichard You're correct—no reason to recompute. I have added an update to the question with this performance change. 2/3 reduction with time! Still think this should be faster though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you do not need to recompute the permutations.

Moreover, `np.array([multiset for _ in _range])` is expensive because Numpy have to transform `multiset` `total_media` times. You can solve that using `np.array([multiset]).repeat(total_media, axis=0)`.

Finally, sympy is not the fastest implementation to perform such a computation. A faster implementation consists in using `itertools` instead:

```py
num_colors = 5
total_media = 300
color_range = list(range(num_colors))
multiset = list(set(itertools.permutations(color_range)))
perm_indices = np.array([multiset], dtype=np.int32).repeat(total_media, axis=0)
```

However, this itertools-based implementation do not preserve the order of the permutations. If this is important, you can use `np.sort` on the Numpy array converted from `multiset` (with a specific axis and before applying `repeat`).

On my machine, this takes about 0.15 ms.